# Como receber dados utilizando Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Fiz uma pequena app de teste, utilizando o FireBase.

Tudo funciona muito bem quando deixo as regras para qualquer um ter acesso ao banco de dados

```
".read":"true",
".write":"true"
```

Mas quando eu adicionei permissões nas rules para limitar os acesso de onde cada usuário pode ler, não consigo mais ler nada na apk.

```
{
  "rules":
  {
    "comandos":
    {
      "$unit_id":
      {
        ".read":"root.child('unidades').child($unit_id).hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write":"root.child('unidades').child($unit_id).hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Quando eu simulo a leitura e gravação no simulador do próprio firebase as regras funcionam perfeitamente. Então imagino que estou fazendo algo errado com a leitura.

O login esta funcionando perfeitamente utilizando o `FirebaseAuth`, recebo a confirmação pelo `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`, mas não sei como "ligar" esse login a minha referencia do Firebase. E quando eu tento realizar o login utilizando

```
mRef = new Firebase(url);
mRef.authWithPassword(email, pass, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler(){...});
```

Recebo a mensagem que devo utilizar o `FirebaseAuth`,

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the 
new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

Devo estar deixando algo extremamente simples passar despercebido, mas não faço ideia de como receber os dados agora que estou exigindo um login, já que a referencia do Firebase `firebase.getAuth()` sempre esta como null, e os dados chegam pelo método

```
firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener(){...});
```

@edit

```
//build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Posta seu gradle por favor

Comment: @christian-beregula seu entendi bem, seu problema é em saber qual é o listener que fica escutando o status da autenticação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era tentar utilizar uma instância da biblioteca antiga do  `Firebase` para tentar receber as notificações do servidor. Ela ainda esta funcional no servidor do Firebase, mas apenas aplicações que já existiam antes da ultima atualização do firebase. As novas aplicações devem utilizar a nova biblioteca `DatabaseReference`, que funcionam junto com a nova biblioteca de login `FirebaseAuth`.

```
//declaração
FirebaseAuth login = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("url");

//função para realizar o login
login.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email", "senha").
    addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            try
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.e("Firebase", "Conectado");

                    //receber atualizações push...
                    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                        {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                        {

                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    Exception e = task.getException();
                    if(e != null)
                    {                       
                        Log.e("Erro login", e+"\n"+task.getResult().toString());
                    }
                    Log.e("Firebase", "Erro de autenticação");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("OnCoplete Erro", e+"");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você não esteja utilizando o novo sdk do android como sugere o erro.

Caso seja isso você deve atualizar seu gradle [veja a documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Para utilizar cada recurso do novo firebase você deve adicionar cada depêndencia separadamente, eis a lista:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0 Analytics
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0 Realtime Database
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.0  Storage
com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0    Crash Reporting
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0 Authentication
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0    Cloud Messaging / Notifications
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.0.0   Remote Config
com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.0  Invites / Dynamic Links
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0  AdMob
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0  App Indexing
```

[Aqui(samples firebase)](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth) você encontra os exemplos do próprio firebase para realizar login com o novo SDK

Comment: O login eu consigo realizar sem problemas, mas não sei como receber os dados do servidor. Estou fazendo algo errado, imagino que esteja relacionado em utilizar uma instancia do Firebase para isso.

Comment: Use o FirebaseAuth como vc comentou em sua pergunta. seu método de login deveria ser algo como na linha 157: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java

Comment: Então, como eu havia dito, o problema não esta no login, esse eu tenho a confirmação que foi efetuado, tanto pelo listener quanto pelo console do firebase. O que não sei o que fazer é um método equivalente ao `firebase.addChildEventListener` que utilize do login do `FirebaseAuth`